# Server-side vs Client-side web application Performance

Tags: c#, javascript, performance, client-side, server-side

I am an entry level programmer with only a few months of experience.
Yesterday I was discussing with a colleague how we can improve the performance of a project we are working on together.

The project is built with C# + Ext.NET + JS

The plan was to move as many things as possible to client-side JavaScript instead of interacting with the server all the time.

I thought this was a good idea, but couldn't help but wonder if there is a point where bringing everything to client-side starts making the web application slower. I understand that interacting with the server and reloading unnecessary data all the time is a waste of time in most cases, but I've also seen websites loaded with so much JS that the browser actually lags and the browsing the web application is just a pain.

Is there a golden point? Are there certain 'rules'? How do you achieve maximum performance? Take Google Cloud apps, such as Docs for example, they're pretty fast for what they do, and they're web applications. That is some very good performance.

Comment: The golden point for performance is quite simple.

If it starts slowing down the computers of people running the application, don't pass it to the client. Otherwise, passing it to the client is the correct thing performance wise.

Comment: I think the one thing missing from your question is the type of calculation you're going to be doing. For instance, are you making a web-based image editor, some sort of database-connected app to let people create/update data, a math program, etc? If the primary concern is loading data asynchronously from the server, my opinion is, as long as that's handled correctly, it's not a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is incredibly fast on the client-side. I assume Ext.NET is like AJAX? If not, you can use AJAX to communicate with the server using JavaScript. It will be pretty fast configured like that. However, the style of coding will change drastically if you're  currently using .NET controls on the DOM with click events.

Comment: Ext.NET is a .NET framework that includes the ExtJS library. What we try to achieve is keep the DOM as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: Use lazy loading of xtypes whenever possible on the client (ie. you can define an xtype but it is only instantiated when it is needed). Especially if those xtypes make ajax calls!

Comment: If you are showing grids of data, usually there is no need to bring down to client more than 100 records from the server at a time, but allow the user to page/search/filter etc....